# Grouping two vectors using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, group-by

I have two vectors `w = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]` and `a = [True, False, True, True, True, True, True]` and I want to group by the numbers in `w` to compute the conjunction of the selected in `a`. So for the given example the result would be `r = [True & False, True & True & True, True & True]`. Is there any nice way to do this computation using Numpy?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how you got `r` from `w` and `a`?

Comment: `a` is got from computed a list of boolean expressions and `w` is pin-pointing which expressions should be conjugated

Comment: You mean r = [True & False, True & True & True, True & True], right?

Comment: Exactly! I'll update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged numpy, you can use list comprehension, [numpy.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [numpy.all](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```py
import numpy as np

w = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
a = np.array([True, False, True, True, True, True, True])
r = [np.all(a[w==i]) for i in np.unique(w)]

r
[False, True, True]
```

Alternatively if you have pandas dependency:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'w':w, 'a':a})
r = df.groupby('w').agg(np.all).reset_index()

r
   w      a
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3   True
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [all(a[np.where(w == i)]) for i in np.unique(w)] 
[False, True, True]
```